# Adding product hyperlink to low stock notification email in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

By default, the low stock notification email contains this text.

- "Product-title" is low in stock. There are "XX" left.

I want to edit this message, in order to add the product hyperlink to the product title.

---

I have found that I can use the following filter hook for this

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_content_low_stock', 'low_stock_dspixel', 10, 2 );

function low_stock_dspixel( $message, $product ) {

    $message = sprintf(/* translators: 1: product name 2: items in stock */
            __( '%1$s is low in stock. There are %2$d left.', 'woocommerce' ),
            html_entity_decode( wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_formatted_name() ), ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) ),
            html_entity_decode( wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) )
        );
 
    return $message;
}
```

How can I further adjust this to add the product hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add/use [WC_Product::get_permalink()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_permalink) – Product permalink to customize `$message` to suit your needs.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_content_low_stock ( $message, $product ) {
    // Edit message
    $message = sprintf(
        /* translators: 1: product name 2: items in stock */
        __( '%1$s is low in stock. There are %2$d left.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . html_entity_decode( wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_formatted_name() ), ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) ) . '</a>',
        html_entity_decode( wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) )
    );
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_content_low_stock', 'filter_woocommerce_email_content_low_stock', 10, 2 );
```

**IMPORTANT:** This answer *will not work by default* because [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) is used as mail function, where the content type is `text/plain` which does not allow using `HTML`

So to send `HTML` formatted emails with WordPress [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), add this extra piece of code

```php
function filter_wp_mail_content_type() {
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'filter_wp_mail_content_type', 10, 0 );
```

---

Related: [Add product link to out of stock email notification in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636011/11987538)