# Add product link to out of stock email notification in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I need to get the product link into out of stock emails sent to admin.

This code does not have the desired result even though I am, as far as I know, using the right filter hook? Any advice?

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_email_content_no_stock', 'add_product_url_to_out_of_stock_email', 10, 2);
function add_product_url_to_out_of_stock_email( $message, $product ) {

    global $product; // with or without this is the same result

    return $message ."<br>\n". get_edit_post_link( $product->get_id() );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add/use [WC_Product::get_permalink()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_permalink) – Product permalink to customize `$message` to suit your needs.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_content_no_stock ( $message, $product ) {
    // Edit message
    $message = sprintf( __( '%s is out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . html_entity_decode( wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_formatted_name() ), ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) ) . '</a>' );
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_content_no_stock', 'filter_woocommerce_email_content_no_stock', 10, 2 );
```

**IMPORTANT:** This answer *will not work by default* because [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) is used as mail function, where the content type is `text/plain` which does not allow using `HTML`

So to send `HTML` formatted emails with WordPress [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), add this extra piece of code

```php
function filter_wp_mail_content_type() {
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'filter_wp_mail_content_type', 10, 0 );
```

---

Related: [Adding product hyperlink to low stock notification email in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177014/adding-product-hyperlink-to-low-stock-notification-email-in-woocommerce/67178555#67178555)